# QML: Attach scrollbar to ListView

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I'm having an issue with ListView. ListView is too long and part of it appears outside of the window but I can't attach a scrollbar. I tried many different combination. I think that problem lies in height parameter but if remove it ListView displays only first entry.

```
Column{
    anchors.fill: parent
    Row{
        id: buttonsRow
            Button{
                text: "Open dump file"
                onClicked: fileDialog.visible = true
            }
            Button{
                text: "Copy raw data to clipboard"
            }
    }
    ListView{
        id: listView
        anchors.top: buttonsRow.bottom
        height: contentHeight
        //clip: true
        flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
        boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
        interactive: true
        model: ListModel{
            id: listModel
        }
        delegate: MDelegate{}
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make it scrollable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting `height` to `contentHeight` is probably the issue. That would make the `ListView` as high as all of its item's heights combined. The scrollbar only works when the height of the view is less than the height of its contents.

Here's an approach that uses layouts instead:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 400
    height: 300
    visible: true

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        RowLayout {
            id: buttonsRow
            Button {
                text: "Open dump file"
            }
            Button {
                text: "Copy raw data to clipboard"
            }
        }

        ListView {
            id: listView
            flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
            boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
            model: 100
            clip: true
            delegate: ItemDelegate {
                text: modelData
            }

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true

            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I don't see, in the code you posted, where you've attached a scrollbar at all. You need to actually include a ScrollBar component in your ListView, like this:

```
    ListView { 
        id: listView
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
        active: true
        }
    }
```

See "Attaching ScrollBar to a Flickable" at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html

Answer (score 2):

```
ScrollBar.vertical:ScrollBar{
            id: listView
            anchors.right: parent.right
            visible: listView.contentHeight > listView.height ? true : false
        }
```