# Qml: ScrollView containing a ListView does not adjust ScrollBar handle

Tags: qt, listview, qml, scrollview

I am trying to add vertical scrollbar, as needed, to a ListView. I have been told that the best approach is to place the ListView inside a ScrollView, instead of inserting a scrollbar into the ListView (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650226/qml-attach-scrollbar-to-listview)), because that would make it more efficient for the GPU.

I inserted it, as in the example below - but no matter what I tried, if the scroll bar shows, its handle always takes the entire height and of course doesn't move.

[image]

I hope you can take a look at my sample and give me a suggestion, why the scroll bar is not showing up properly.
There are comments inside the code explaining what I did and why.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

Item
{
    readonly property int parentWidth: 280
    readonly property int parentMaxHeight: 400

    // Main reason for doing this - the items are custom objects and
    // their width does not automatically adjust for having the scroll bar or not
    // But also, to set scroll bars because Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded makes them not show
    property bool scrollBarVisible: myListView.contentHeight > myListView.height

    width: parentWidth
    height: parentMaxHeight

    Rectangle
    {
        id: myMenuRect

        anchors.rightMargin: 2
        anchors.leftMargin: 2
        anchors.bottomMargin: 4
        anchors.topMargin: 4

        width: parentWidth
        height: myListView.height
        radius: 10
        z: 2

        color: "red"   // Adding this to show why the height of the rectangle must match the listview
    }

    ScrollView
    {
        id: myScrollView
        parent: myMenuRect
        anchors.fill: parent

        anchors.topMargin: 5
        anchors.bottomMargin: 5
        anchors.rightMargin: 5

        frameVisible: false

        // I have tried to set implicitHeight in many different ways,
        // no matter what I do the scroll bar handle occupies the enire bar and doesn't move

        // The Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded didn't work... so I did this
        verticalScrollBarPolicy: scrollBarVisible ? Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn : Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff

    // Adding colors on scrollbar to show which part is showing     
    style: ScrollViewStyle
    {
        handle: Rectangle
        {
            implicitWidth: 10
            implicitHeight: 2
            radius: 10
            anchors.leftMargin: 1
            anchors.left: parent.left
            color: "yellow"
        }

        scrollBarBackground: Rectangle
        {
            implicitWidth: 12
            anchors.right: parent.right
            color: "green"
        }
    }

    ListView
    {
        id: myListView
        parent: myScrollView
        model: wifiComboListModel

        focus: true
        clip: true
        interactive: false

        width: parent.width

        // I am trying to tell my view to take the minimum space it needs that is below 
        // a certain height. Ignore the "myListView." prefixes here, I know they are not needed but 
        // make it easier to move this outside if needed
        height: (myListView.contentHeight > 0 ?
                     (myListView.contentHeight < parentMaxHeight ?
                          myListView.contentHeight : parentMaxHeight) : 0)

        // I made this as simple as possible, without affecting "quality"
        delegate: Text
        {
            text: _comboBoxText
            height: 70
            width: parent.width - 20
        }
    }

    ListModel
    {
        id: wifiComboListModel
    }

    // I want to populate my model from outside, not be static. Not sure if this affects the bars
    function populateComboBoxListModel()
    {
        wifiComboListModel.clear();
        for (var itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < listItems.length; itemIndex++)
        {
            wifiComboListModel.append
                ({
                    _id: itemIndex,
                    _comboBoxText: listItems[itemIndex]
                });
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        populateComboBoxListModel();
    }

    property var listItems: [
            "This",
            "annoying",
            "list",
            "view",
            "does",
            "not behave the way",
            "I expect.",
            "I",
            "tried many",
            "things,",
            "now I am",
            "begging for your",
            "help",
            "."
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a binding loop for height in myMenuRect. This occurs because myMenuRect depends on height of the list view and vice versa. After fixing it seems to be working:

[image]

```
import QtQuick 2.0 
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow
{
    readonly property int parentWidth: 280
    readonly property int parentMaxHeight: 400
    visible: true

    // Main reason for doing this - the items are custom objects and
    // their width does not automatically adjust for having the scroll bar or not
    // But also, to set scroll bars because Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded makes them not show
    property bool scrollBarVisible: myListView.contentHeight > myListView.height

    width: parentWidth
    height: parentMaxHeight

    Rectangle
    {
        id: myMenuRect

        anchors.rightMargin: 2
        anchors.leftMargin: 2
        anchors.bottomMargin: 4
        anchors.topMargin: 4

        width: parentWidth
        height: parentMaxHeight
        radius: 10
        z: 2
    }

    ScrollView
    {
        id: myScrollView
        parent: myMenuRect
        anchors.fill: parent

        anchors.topMargin: 5
        anchors.bottomMargin: 5
        anchors.rightMargin: 5

        frameVisible: false

        // I have tried to set implicitHeight in many different ways,
        // no matter what I do the scroll bar handle occupies the enire bar and doesn't move

        // The Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded didn't work... so I did this
        verticalScrollBarPolicy: scrollBarVisible ? Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn : Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff

        ListView
        {
            id: myListView
            model: wifiComboListModel

            focus: true
            clip: true
            interactive: false

            width: parent.width

            // I am trying to tell my view to take the minimum space it needs that is below
            // a certain height. Ignore the "myListView." prefixes here, I know they are not needed but
            // make it easier to move this outside if needed
            height: (myListView.contentHeight > 0 ?
                         (myListView.contentHeight < parentMaxHeight ?
                              myListView.contentHeight : parentMaxHeight) : 0)

            // I made this as simple as possible, without affecting "quality"
            delegate: Text
            {
                text: _comboBoxText
                height: 70
                width: parent.width - 20
            }
        }
    }

    ListModel
    {
        id: wifiComboListModel
    }

    // I want to populate my model from outside, not be static. Not sure if this affects the bars
    function populateComboBoxListModel()
    {
        wifiComboListModel.clear();
        for (var itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < listItems.length; itemIndex++)
        {
            wifiComboListModel.append
                ({
                    _id: itemIndex,
                    _comboBoxText: listItems[itemIndex]
                });
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        populateComboBoxListModel();
    }

    property var listItems: [
            "This",
            "annoying",
            "list",
            "view",
            "does",
            "not behave the way",
            "I expect.",
            "I",
            "tried many",
            "things,",
            "now I am",
            "begging for your",
            "help",
            "."
    ]
}
```

Comment: I am sorry this still does not work for me. The change only makes that the rectangle has a fixed max size, the reason I related it to the listview was so hat it adjusts the size based on content. Once my colleague helped fixed the problem, I did see the binding loop error too, I will have to calculate the height differently - so the issue you pointed out is valid. I will explain below what fixed the issue.

Comment: The fix - which is contained in your code but you did not point it out - was to physically nest the ListView inside the ScrollView. I am explaining this in an answer below, perhaps it will help other people, but I am upvoting and marking your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why my ScrollView did not behave was parenthood :)

The issue: even though I set the parent in the ListView, it seems it did not take:

```
ListView
{
    parent: myScrollView
```

What I had to do to make it work was actually nest the ListView inside the ScrollView.

```
ScrollView
{
    id: myScrollView
    parent: myMenuRect
    anchors.fill: parent

    ListView
    {
        id: myListView
        model: wifiComboListModel
```

I think the "parent" property may not work well for all controls, and will remember that in the future.